# Array in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell

What am I doing wrong here?

The mailbox has an active an inactive mailbox so it will return two mailboxes.
However, when trying to capture the output, I am only getting the last account in the array
Note, this is a simplified version of a larger script, but kept it simple for this example.

```
$guid = import-csv "c:\temp\Mailboxes.csv"

$DAta = New-Object psobject
$Data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name alias -Value $null
$Data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name guid -Value $null

$mbxcol = @()

#$data = $null

foreach ($G in $Guid){

    $mbx = Get-mailbox $g.alias -IncludeInactiveMailbox

    $data.alias = $mbx.alias
    $data.guid = $mbx.guid

    $MBXCol += $Data
}

$mbxcol
```

Comment: you're calling `$guid = get-mailbox YuTe.Wu@fda.hhs.gov ...` at the top but then in your loop you're querying, _presumably_, the same mailbox again `Get-mailbox $g.alias...`, why?

Comment: updated to use CSV file

Comment: all your array elements are a reference of the same object, that's the issue. you need to instantiate a new object per loop iteration instead of updating the same object over and over

Answer (score 2):

As explained in comments, every array element is a reference of the same object (`$Data`), a simple way to demonstrate using [`Object.ReferenceEquals` Mehod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-6.0) with this example:

```bash
foreach ($item in 0..10) {
    $data.Alias = 'mailbox{0}' -f $item
    $data.Guid  = [guid]::NewGuid()
    $mbxcol    += $data
}

[object]::ReferenceEquals($data, $mbxcol[0]) # -> True
```

As for how to simplify and make your code more efficient, [**do not add elements (`+=`) to a fixed collection (`@( )`)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle):

```bash
$result = (Import-Csv "c:\temp\Mailboxes.csv").Alias |
    Get-Mailbox -IncludeInactiveMailbox |
        Select-Object Alias, Guid
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more simple example of your code is:

```
$guid = ("A","B")

$Data = New-Object psobject
$Data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name alias -Value $null

$mbxcol = @()

foreach ($G in $Guid){

$mbx = $g

$data.alias = $mbx

$MBXCol += $Data
}

$mbxcol
```

As @Santiago mentioned in his comment, `$Data` is a reference to an object, so each time you update it, you overwrite it, even if it is in an array. To fix this, instantiate the object each loop as follows:

```
$guid = ("A","B")

$mbxcol = @()

foreach ($G in $Guid){
$Data = New-Object psobject
$Data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name alias -Value $null

$mbx = $g

$data.alias = $mbx

$MBXCol += $Data
}

$mbxcol
```